# Why does this code produce the error "AttributeError: 'Match' object has no attribute 'replace'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

With the following basic script, I am able to get all current matches using the [sports](https://pypi.org/project/sports.py/) package:

```
import sports
all_matches = sports.all_matches()
s = all_matches['soccer']
print(s)

>> [Saham 1-2 Al Shabab, Cuanda Cubango FC 1-2 Academica Lobito, Recreativo Da Caala 0-2 Primeiro De Agosto, Progresso Associacao 0-0 Santa Rita De Cassia, Wapda 1-1 Karachi Electric, Tooro United 2-0 Bright Stars FC, Bul FC 2-2 Nyamityobora, Paidha Black Angels 1-1 Maroons FC, Express FC 0-0 Ndejje University, Pakistan Navy 1-0 National Bank, La Roda 0-0 Atletico Ibanes] [Finished in 10.4s]
```

---

I am looking to split the list so that I get a match per line like so:

```
import sports
all_matches = sports.all_matches()
s = all_matches['soccer']
soccer = [i.replace(',', '\n') for i in s]
print(soccer)
```

---

```
AttributeError: 'Match' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Hoped output:

```
>>[Saham 1-2 Al Shabab
>>Cuanda Cubango FC 1-2 Academica Lobito
>>Recreativo Da Caala 0-2 Primeiro De Agosto
>>Progresso Associacao 0-0 Santa Rita De Cassia
>>Wapda 1-1 Karachi Electric
>>Tooro United 2-0 Bright Stars FC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Match`](https://github.com/evansloan/sports.py/blob/c7dda8ebb156878bf558bc4cd234c4cf2bfa2299/sports/scores.py#L10) class in the library that you are using defines identical `__repr__` and `__str__` methods which return a string comprising the home team name, the home team score, the away team score and the away team name.  That's why you see the results when you print the list of matches.

Your variable `s` is a `list` of `Match` objects.

There are two ways to print each match on a separate line.

You can use for loop to print each match:

```
>>> for m in matches:
...     print(m)
... 
Saham 1-2 Al Shabab
Cuanda Cubango FC 1-2 Academica Lobito
Recreativo Da Caala 0-2 Primeiro De Agosto
Progresso Associacao 0-0 Santa Rita De Cassia
Wapda 1-1 Karachi Electric
Tooro United 2-0 Bright Stars FC
Bul FC 2-2 Nyamityobora
Paidha Black Angels 1-1 Maroons FC
Express FC 0-0 Ndejje University
Pakistan Navy 1-0 National Bank
La Roda 0-0 Atletico Ibanes
```

or you can join the string representation of all the objects together, with newlines inbetween, using the [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in matches))
Saham 1-2 Al Shabab
Cuanda Cubango FC 1-2 Academica Lobito
Recreativo Da Caala 0-2 Primeiro De Agosto
Progresso Associacao 0-0 Santa Rita De Cassia
Wapda 1-1 Karachi Electric
Tooro United 2-0 Bright Stars FC
Bul FC 2-2 Nyamityobora
Paidha Black Angels 1-1 Maroons FC
Express FC 0-0 Ndejje University
Pakistan Navy 1-0 National Bank
La Roda 0-0 Atletico Ibanes
```